# Text padding inside wx.StaticText

Tags: wxpython

I have a wx.StaticText control inside my wxpython phoenix app. I want the text to appear on a certain background color and have some "air" or padding around the text. Doing a `SetBackgroudnColour(RED)` does indeed set the correct background color. But how to give the text inside some more room ?

UPDATE: See image below to see what I mean.

[image]

I guess this could be done using resizing the textbox and event bindings to resize the textbox if needed. But my attempts like below did not give a proper result (the sizer in which this component is in does not layout properly). Any help welcome.

```py
    def _on_resize(self,event):
        try:
            size = self.text_box.GetSize()
            _y = 2 * size[1]
            self.text_box.SetSize(wx.Size(size[0], _y))

        except AttributeError:
            pass
        event.Skip()
```

Comment: Why don't you create an image of what it is that you want to achieve and add it to the question. Talk of padding, "air", borders and "tight" boxes is a little imprecise. A picture is worth a thousand words, some bright-spark once said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep mentioning textbox but I assume that you do not mean a `wx.StaticBox` as it is never specifically mentioned. Note that there is a `wx.StaticBoxSizer` if you are referring to a `StaticBox`.
You can always just pad out a vertical boxsizer and perhaps fiddle with the font size to adjust the "air" around your text.
Here is an ugly example:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        text1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Tight Text')
        text1.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        text1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

        text2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "  Loose text in a box  ")
        text3 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "  Tighter text in a box  ")
        text4 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Tighter text in a box", size=(130,30), style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_CENTRE)
        t21 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "")
        t22 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "")
        t31 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "")
        t32 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "")

        text2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        text2.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        text3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        text3.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        text4.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        t21.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        t22.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        t31.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        t32.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        text4.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

        sbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sbox.Add(t21,0 ,wx.EXPAND,0)
        sbox.Add(text2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sbox.Add(t22,0,wx.EXPAND,0)

        font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
        font.SetPointSize(2)
        sbox1=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        t31.SetFont(font)
        t32.SetFont(font)
        sbox1.Add(t31,0 ,wx.EXPAND,0)
        sbox1.Add(text3, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sbox1.Add(t32,0,wx.EXPAND,0)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(text1,0,wx.ALL,5)
        sizer.Add(sbox,0,wx.ALL,5)
        sizer.Add(sbox1,0,wx.ALL,5)
        sizer.Add(text4,0,wx.ALL,5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
top = MyFrame("My Window")
app.MainLoop()
```

Please ignore my `import` statement as under '4.0.4 gtk2 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5' on Linux, setting background colour for static texts seems to fail completely and I am forcing a different version of `wx`

[image]

Comment: @sanders Indeed! Perhaps you would be better off using a `TextCtrl` and setting it read only. I've edited my answer to include it, just in case it serves your purpose.